# Allow access to Azure Services equivalent for Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have IP address restrictions set on an Azure Web App. These work fine for applications from various locations calling into Azure for a Web App.

We now want to extend these to allow Azure services to access this resource but I cannot seem to get this working. On some other Azure resources (e.g. Azure SQL) there is a button to press that allows access from other Azure services but this does not exist on the Web Apps.

I've also tried:

- Adding the outbound IP addresses to the firewall.
- Adding all the IP addresses in the known outbound IP Addresses for the region.

Couldn't find any information on what the IP address range should be between two Azure services.

Comment: I'm quite sure you need to whitelist the whole Azure region service is in (we are talking PaaS, for IaaS you can whitelist specific Ip addresses), or at least the service you are interested in (if it has its ranges published somewhere)

Comment: Yeah I was looking for ranges but the ones I've found didn't seem to work

Comment: you saw this json feed with service tags? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Comment: Yes, that's the one I tried. Specifically I added AppService.UKWest IP addresses listed and none of them worked.

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Basically I've got an application that I only want accessible to certain IP addresses. This works fine for IP addresses outside of Azure.

If I want to do this for Azure services, then I've found the outbound IP addresses don't seem to work. My assumption is that it's not leaving the datacentre and has a different IP address.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to another Azure web app(B) to access your Azure web app(A) which mapped white list, you can just add out-bound IP of web app B into A's white list .You can find B's out-bound IP here : [image]

I have did a quick test between two Azure web apps using webjobs http calling and it works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that's one of the things I've tried unsuccessfully. I'm guessing it's because I'm using a consumption plan which means those IP addresses are not necessarily the ones I'll actually be using. I could try a cheaper app service plan to confirm that is the issue come to think of it

Comment: Hello Daniel, if you want to white list your Consumption plan function out bound IP address, you may need to whitelist the entire data center out bound IPs where your function add located .

Comment: That's what I tried (in the second point on my post). For clarity this is a function app on a consumption plan in UKWest communicating with a Web App in UK West on an S1 app service plan. I took the values out of the downloaded ServiceTags_Public_20190708.json file for `AppService.UKWest`.

Comment: Hello Daniel , I created a consumption function app and a web app hosted on S1 plan and all of them located in west UK just like yours . I enabled whist list on my web app and adding all Azure Datacenter IP Ranges of west UK (I get IP list here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653) . Everything works as excepted , my function app can access my web app successfully but I got 403 while accessing my web app from local . Could you pls have a check ?